# Here, "married" is a "verb" or "adjective"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

She is **married** to an Englishman.

I wants to know its lexical categories?(Whether a **verb** or **adjective** )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We use **`ed`** with adjectives to describe our feeling like:

I'm embarrassed

I'm married

I'm annoyed.

> We use **`ing`** with adjectives to explaine something is the reason of my feeling like:

That was embarrassing

It's fascinating.

And if you pay attention we already have verb **`to be`** verb.

Married is a kind of adjective we use for someone to show they is especial. So it isn't verb, the verb of married is **`get married`**.

I **am** married.

> **`Sobject`**+**`to be verb`**+**`adjective`**.

You can even say **I'm boring** but it means **you are that reason, who or what makes others to feel borned.**

I read comments, they said you can say I'm married means `Now` its cosequences are happening "presenent continuous".

It's correct but personal I would like to use get before that: I'm getting married.
The common verb of married is get married.
I'm getting married. I got married. We will get married. Etc.

Comment: It resembles passive voice.

Comment: Good answer, but I believe you mean "to show they **are special**"?

Comment: I wanted to say the gender was unspecified.

Comment: @SajjadKhorrami Oh, sorry! I misunderstood.

Comment: There is also the verb **to marry**: a) "*Do you want to marry Peter?* b) *He married his long-term partner last year* c) *They will marry at the end of May*

Comment: It's worth mentioning the name for this kind of adjective formed from a verb:  it is a **participle adjective**.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is an adjective because it is an attribute of someone.
Here is an example: **I am married to Alice.**

Comment: Why can't be a verb?

Comment: @Sam It **can** be a verb - if so, it would be the *present indicative passive* of "to marry" - with **an important caveat**. That is that the verb form is actually the two-word phrase **is married** and not just **married** on its own. In the sentence from your question, it makes more sense for it to be an adjective than this passive form of the verb. In other contexts, it might be the other way around.

Comment: @Sam Active voice: "She marries an Englishman." Passive voice: "She is married to an Englishman" - **but** the meaning of that sentence would be that **at this present moment** she is **getting married** to the Englishman. I don't think that's the meaning you're trying to convey.  If you're referring to the **state** of being married and not the **act** of getting married, then "She is married..." must be interpreted as **subject-linking verb-predicate adjective**.

Comment: @Sam But, you're correct that the adjective comes from the verb "to marry"! It's what's called a "deverbal adjective" or sometimes just "verbal adjective". With a small change to your sentence, you can get something like this: "**Married** to an Englishman last summer, she will be moving to London tomorrow." In **that** sentence, the word **married** is the past (or *perfect*) participle of "to marry," which means it's a verb form which is *used as* an adjective.  So, sometimes it can be both!